# Am i Running Linux or Unix on this computer

Tags: linux, unix

So, I downloaded Ubuntu and ran it through a Virtual Machine, with the expectation (hoping) that I would be running Linux. After typing `uname -a`, I thought all was well (first output), but when I started doing some password stuff it said enter new UNIX password (second output). Does that mean I'm running UNIX or does that not matter? Based on these two outputs, could someone please tell me if I'm running UNIX or Linux? (I'm using a Mac so could that possibly affect the fact that it said enter new UNIX Password. I don't think it should since I'm running the terminal on the virtual machine.)

```
trevor@trevor-VirtualBox:/$ uname -a
Linux trevor-VirtualBox 3.11.0-15-generic #25~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:39:31 UTC           
2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

Comment: Of course, it's Linux :)

Comment: which is a UNIX clone anyway.

Comment: why does it say add new UNIX password then?

Comment: Some people make a fuss about Linux not being UNIX and may even bring up arcane reasons why this distinction should be made.  For the other 99.999% of us, Linux is a form of UNIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux is based on UNIX.

Per [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-and-unix/):

> Linux is a Unix clone written from scratch by Linus Torvalds with assistance from a loosely-knit team of hackers across the Net. It aims towards POSIX compliance.

For all practical purposes, Linux is a continuation of UNIX by the Open Source community.

Comment: UNIX is an entire operating system (which exists in a number of variants). The name Linux, strictly speaking, refers only to the kernel, but it's common to use the name to refer to an entire operating system built around the Linux kernel. [This usage is controversial](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/why-gnu-linux.html) (and debating it in comments would not be constructive).